# Instalar gloss de Haskell en Mac OS Catalina

Tags: haskell, macos

Estoy intentando **instalar la librería [gloss](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss) de Haskell,** en Mac OS Catalina, pero estoy teniendo muchos problemas.

Lo que primero hice fue seguir los pasos de [esta página](https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html), para instalar Haskell.

**Ya con cabal instalado** (el link anterior lo descarga) use el comando `cabal install gloss`. Pero me dice el siguiente error:

```
❯ cabal install gloss                                                                                 
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Cannot build the executables in the package gloss because it does not
contain any executables. Check the .cabal file for the package and make sure
that it properly declares the components that you expect.
```

A su vez, ya hice `cabal update`. Y después otra vez `cabal install gloss`, pero nada.

Comment: Si has seguido esas instrucciones, se supone que has instalado `stack`. Compruébalo con `stack config env`

Comment: Si, tengo instalado `stack`. Hice lo que me decís pero me salto error (por las versiones). Pero hice `stack ghci Main.hs` (ese `Main.hs` es mi archivo que tiene importado gloss) pero me salta el mismo error de antes, que no esta instalado gloss.

Comment: ¿Y con `stack install gloss` qué te dice?

Comment: Me tira esto: 
`Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 8.6, and using 8.8.2, this may fail

Stack has not been tested with Cabal versions above 2.4, but version 3.0.1.0 was found, this may fail `

Comment: Evidentemente, la instalación no está bien. Tendrás que desintalar y volver a instalar forzando las versiones de stack y cabal-install para que sean compatibles. Mi recomendación es que no uses las últimas versiones. Quédate con alguna de las LTS. Lamentablemente, tendrás que ir probando hasta acertar.